# Fazer join em tabela que possui dois ID na mesma coluna

Tags: sql, join

O cenário é o seguinte: eu tenho minhas tabelas de ordens de serviços e minhas tabelas de agendamentos dos técnicos para cada ordem de serviço.
O problema é: Na minha tabela de OS eu tenho, por exemplo, os protocolos "123" e "456".
Na minha tabela de agendamento, na minha coluna de "ID_OS", eu possuo o seguinte valor: "B:123 T:456", isso no mesmo campo, pois se refere a um agendamento para dois produtos (banda larga e telefone).

Como é possível eu sair da minha tabela de OS, que vai ter uma linha para o ID 123 e uma linha para o ID 456 e realizar um join que considere esses casos de produtos duplos que vão aparecer, na mesma coluna, na mesma célula, os valores "B:123 T:456" ?

O cenário ideal é eu trazer, no resultado, uma linha para a OS 123, com a informação do técnico, e uma linha para a OS 456, com as mesmas informações do técnico, mas preciso dessas duas linhas.

Segue o SQL Fiddle contendo um exemplo do estado atual do banco: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/38269b/3

Comment: A OS 789 deve ter apenas uma linha também? Seu resultado então teria três linhas com os dados do link? Consegue colocar um exemplo de como você gostaria que fosse o resultado dessa query.

Comment: Certamente não é uma boa prática você ter atributos multivalorados em sua tabela. Não diria que é impossível você fazer o join mas seria muito mais simples se os atributos de sua tabela fossem atômicos.

Comment: Infelizmente não consigo mudar a tabela, não tenho poder sobre isso e o sistema já cria dessa maneira.

Comment: @DanielMendes sim, a OS 780 tem que ter só uma linha, coloquei ela no exemplo porque não são todas que acontecem esse problema de atributos multivalorados.
No final eu preciso de três linhas: Uma para cada OS contendo alguns dados da tabela de técnicos.

Comment: Seria esse o resultado esperado: https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7MhK.png

Comment: @DanielMendes exato, a SO 123 e 456 com informações extras da tabela de técnicos, que só tem uma linha para essas duas SO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como os dados estão presentes na `SO_TABLE` sem formatação, uma possível solução é procurar fazer o `join` dessas tabelas utilizando o `like` do SQL.

Se o dado presente em `TECH_TABLE.SO_ID` estiver contido no `SO_TABLE.SO_ID`, ele será considerado.

Veja um exemplo de forma fazer isso:

```
SELECT *
  FROM SO_TABLE SO
  JOIN TECH_TABLE TE
    ON TE.SO_ID LIKE '%' || SO.SO_ID ||'%';
```

Fica a seu critério e regra de negócio fazer um `left join`, `right join` etc, como achar melhor.

---

Caso o like esteja muito amplo, você pode trabalhar com as característica de formatação presentes na tabela `TECH_TABLE`, utilizando a letra e dois pontos (`'B:'`):

```
SELECT *
  FROM SO_TABLE SO
  JOIN TECH_TABLE TE
    ON ( TE.SO_ID = SO.SO_ID
      OR TE.SO_ID LIKE '%B:' || SO.SO_ID || '%'
      OR TE.SO_ID LIKE '%T:' || SO.SO_ID || '%' );
```

Com isso eu trago o ID contido nas letras ou a igualdade do ID.

---

Se existirem muitas letras, é possível filtrar apenas o dois pontos:

```
SELECT *
  FROM SO_TABLE SO
  JOIN TECH_TABLE TE
    ON ( TE.SO_ID = SO.SO_ID
      OR TE.SO_ID LIKE '%:' || SO.SO_ID || '%' );
```

Igualdade de ID ou ':' e ID contido.

---

> Veja online: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/38269b/37

Comment: Acredito que está correto, pelo que estou vendo aqui. Não havia pensado em usar o like no join. Vou só dar uma verificada para ter certeza de que não vai pegar OS errada e tudo mais, por causa do like, e também preciso ver se não vai ficar muito lenta e pesada a query. Mas obrigado, me ajudou bastante.

Answer (score 0):

Eu vi ali que vc está usando Oracle... não manjo de PL/SQL, mas se fosse no SQL Server eu faria algo parecedo com isso:

SELECT * FROM TECH_TABLE  AS A
CROSS APPLY (SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(value,'D:',''),'F:','') AS ITEM FROM SPLIT_STRING(A.SO_ID,' ')) B;
INNER JOIN SO_TABLE AS C
ON B.ITEM = C.SO_ID

Usuaria cross apply com split para quebrar e tratar o código e em seguida faria um join com a outra tabela.
Se der erro no inner join após o cross, inverte eles.